# sorting multiple fields in one array-c++

Tags: c++, sorting

I want to sort the values of the third column and the the same time, the values of columns one and two follows the same position as the third column **using an array.**

for example

Before sorting

```
2 30 2000
1 40 1000
3 10 4000
5 20 3000
4 50 5000
```

After sorting

```
1 40 1000
2 30 2000
5 20 3000
3 10 4000
4 50 5000
```

I know it could be done by using a vector and a std::sort but is it possible to use a array to achieve the same results?

Comment: How do you represent rows and columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `std::sort` to sort the array, you can use `std::begin` and `std::end` to obtain iterators to the start and end to pass to `sort`, and you can use `std::tuple` to provide the comparison function.

There is no particularly relevant difference between `std::vector` and a raw array for this task.

Example code:

```
#include <algorithm>        // std::sort
#include <iterator>         // std::begin, std::end
#include <iostream>         // std::cout, std::endl
#include <tuple>            // std::tie
using namespace std;

struct Triplet { int values[3]; };

template< int n >
void display( Triplet const (&array)[n] )
{
    for( auto const& t : array )
    {
        cout << t.values[0] << ' ' << t.values[1] << ' ' << t.values[2] << endl;
    }
}

auto main()
    -> int
{
    Triplet array[]  =
    {
        { 2, 30, 2000 },
        { 1, 40, 1000 },
        { 3, 10, 4000 },
        { 5, 20, 3000 },
        { 4, 50, 5000 }
    };

    auto const triplet_less = []( Triplet const& a, Triplet const& b ) -> bool
    {
        return 
            (tie( a.values[2], a.values[0], a.values[1] ) <
                tie( b.values[2], b.values[0], b.values[1] ));
    };

    cout << "Original data: " << endl;
    display( array );

    sort( begin( array ), end( array ), triplet_less );

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Sorted data: " << endl;
    display( array );
}
```